# Rails Presenter block method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

EDIT:

I got many responses with different approaches for solving the problem, thanks a lot!

Sadly, none of them worked until now.

To easily understand and reproduce the failure, I created a small Rails repo on **[GitHub](https://github.com/astropanic/presenter_test)** with a Rspec suite.

One of the specs is passing (where the presenter is initialized in the view).
One of the specs is failing (where the presenter is initialized in the controller).

**How make them both pass ?**

ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW:

This is my Presenter:

```
class UserPresenter
  def initialize(user, vc)
    @user = user
    @vc   = vc
  end

  def linkify()
    #
    # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    #
    vc.link_to("foo") do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

This is my Controller:

I initialize my Presenter in the controller, passing the view context of the controller with the presented model.

```
class UserController
  def show
    @user = User.find(#.....
    @presenter = UserPresenter.new(@user, view_context)
  end
end
```

In my Slim template, I call my Presenter to put the content in a link:

```
=@presenter.linkify do
  p "123"
```

My problem is, I can't pass the block from the view to my `linkify` method.

In the with comment marked above code, the passed block is the whole view content, instead of the `p 123`.

When I initialize my Presenter in the view via: `@presenter = UserPresenter.new(@user, self)`, it works as expected.

**How I can make the linkify method uses the provided block, without initializing the presenter in the view ?**

Comment: probably an indentation level issue

Comment: not really, I got the <p>123</p> but not wrapped in the link as expected

Comment: yes i tried fiddling with this and can't see the obvious issue :-/

Answer (score 2):

Because if you are going to use the yield command, you mustn't specify the &block, since now you are effectively receiving a block as a parameter using normal parameter syntax.

```
class UserPresenter
  def initialize(user, vc)
    @user = user
    @vc   = vc
  end

  def linkify() # <-- Remove &block
    vc.link_to("foo") do
      yield
    end
  end
end

# ...
# Somewhere else, assuming you have access to @presenter which is an instance of
# UserPresenter
# ...

def show
  @presenter.linkify do
    # ...
    # do my view stuff here
    # ...
  end
end

show()

# Now, if your "View" is nothing but a block that needs to get passed in
# then you'd do this...

def show(&block)
  @presenter.linkify do
    block.call()
  end
end

# This would be used this way:

show(lambda {  
  # ...
  # View stuff here
  # ..
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this don't helped me. Please see my updated question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, even without the &block it still doesn't work... , look at the above repo, you will see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in lacrosse's answer. The wrong view context is the root of this cause. I tried to make a work around for your situation. And, this is how ended up doing it:

I created a helper method in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link(presenter)
    presenter.linkify(self) do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

changed linkify() to:

```
def linkify(vc)
  vc.link_to("foo") do
    yield
  end
end
```

which means, no need to have **vc** in presenter's class constructer, or you can update the **vc** in `link` method defined in the helper(your choice).

views are now looks something like this:

**presenter_from_view.html.slim**:

```
-@presenter = UserPresenter.new(@user, self)
=link @presenter do
  p 123
```

**presenter_from_controller.html.slim**:

```
=link @presenter do
  p 123
```

I agree, maybe this is not how you wanted your solution to be done. But, I couldn't get any cleaner work around for this. However, here you **don't** have to **worry** about passing `self` in views wherever you use `link @presenter do..`(which may become too much for writing code when you use linkify in multiple views I guess).

P.S.: Your all specs are passing now. And, if you need the modified code then I can push it to your repository in a separate branch. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

From [Slim's documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Helpers_and_capturing) on Helpers and Capturing:

```
module Helpers
  def headline(&block)
    if defined?(::Rails)
      # In Rails we have to use capture!
      "<h1>#{capture(&block)}</h1>"
    else
      # If we are using Slim without a framework (Plain Tilt),
      # this works directly.
      "<h1>#{yield}</h1>"
    end
  end
end
```

Can you try using capture as follows?

```
def linkify(&block)
  result = capture(&block)
  vc.link_to("foo") do
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, nice try ;) https://github.com/astropanic/presenter_test/commit/d0fc57e921cee5a0769d27a9cb705bf9fcda9278

Answer (score 1):

The wrong view context is causing this issue. Just change `UserPresenter#initialize` to not accept view context, initialize presenter in the controller and pass the correct view context from the view instead, like so:

```
= @presenter.linkify(self) do
  p "123"
```

Comment: Yes, this is a option, but the question is about initializing the presenter with the view from the controller. It is inconvinient, to pass to each presenter method self as one of the arguments.

Comment: As [view_context](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.5/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L75:L77) return value is not being cached, it returns different instances each time, so I don't think there are other options if you want to operate with the correct view context.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? Just looking at the code...

In this method

```
def linkify()
  #
  # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
  #
  vc.link_to("foo") do
    yield
  end
end
```

where is **vc** defined?

I think you mean **@vc** which is the instance variable you're initializing.

Also as a side note... the empty () in linkify() are redundant in a ruby method with no variables. You can eliminate them.

Also you may want to take a look at the [cells gem](https://github.com/apotonick/cells). As you're basically mirroring this behavior in your presenters and IMO cells is a cleaner way of accomplishing this in rails.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out WHY it's not working. When you pass in the view_context in the controller, it's rendering the view_context once when you pass it in to the presenter, and then you again when you actually render the view.

```
def initialize(user, vc)
  @user = user
  @vc = vc
end

# When called from the view:
@presenter = UserPresenter.new(@user, self)
# You're passing the view directly in "as is" and renders as expected.

# However, when you pass it in from the controller:
@presenter = UserPresent.new(@user, view_context)
# you're essentially rendering the view_context in the controller, and then again
# once it renders at the end of your action. That's why you're getting this:
#   "<p>123</p><a href="foo"><p>123</p></a>"
```

You'll either need to send self in from the view each time you call linkify, or you can use an application helper method that will always have the view context.